# How can i check the status of a Jenkins Job in Powershell?

Tags: jenkins

I have a job in Jenkins and added a build step that runs some Powershell. Now if the job fails half way in the Powershell script I want to be able to capture the build_status.

do i need to wrap the powershell code around a try catch ?

How can i do that with the variable BUILD_STATUS ?

UpdateL:

this is only some of the scripts in powershell in jenkins i run:

New-AzSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName "RG01" -ServerName "Server01" -DatabaseName "Database01" -StorageKeyType "StorageAccessKey" -StorageKey "StorageKey01" -StorageUri "http://account01.blob.core.contoso.net/bacpacs/database01.bacpac" -AdministratorLogin "User" -AdministratorLoginPassword "secure password

Now if the ResourceGroup is wrong then it will fail and should not go to the next line.. How can i do an exit 1 ?

Comment: If you get powershell to exit 1 when it fails, that would fail the stage, the job and make the build status get marked as failure?

Comment: So in jenkins i am doing the following :  I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this command but if it doesn't automatically throw a terminating error when the RG is wrong, you could use [ErrorAction](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/erroraction-and-errorvariable/) to force it to stop:

```
New-AzSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName "RG01" ...  -ErrorAction Stop
```

If that doesn't work, according to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/new-azsqldatabaseexport?view=azps-11.3.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-11.0.0), the output of the command should give you a result like this:

```
New-AzSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName "RG01" -ServerName "Server01" -DatabaseName "Database01" -StorageKeyType "StorageAccessKey" -StorageKey "StorageKey01" -StorageUri "http://account01.blob.core.contoso.net/bacpacs/database01.bacpac" -AdministratorLogin "User" -AdministratorLoginPassword "secure password"

ResourceGroupName          : RG01
ServerName                 : Server01
DatabaseName               : Database01
StorageKeyType             : StorageAccessKey
StorageKey                 : 
StorageUri                 : http://account01.blob.core.contoso.net/bacpacs/database01.bacpac
AdministratorLogin         : User
AdministratorLoginPassword : 
AuthenticationType         : None
OperationStatusLink        : https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/resource01/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/server01/databases/database01/importExportOperationResults/00000000-00
                             0-0000-0000-000000000000?api-version=2014-04-01
Status                     : InProgress
ErrorMessage               :
```

You could parse this output and see if there is anything is the `ErrorMessage` field. If there is, run `exit 1`.

Comment: Yes but there are more than one line , it is a block of Powershell code and could error anywhere